# How do I programmatically set a user as spam in BuddyPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am working on a (WordPress) moderation tool. One of the actions I want my moderators to be able to achieve is setting a user account as spam. I know how to do so via the UI as admin but how do I do the same via code?

A pointer to the right documentation would be enough I'm just struggling with this a bit and Google is (unusually) failing me.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, but I'm fetching from memory here, IIRC, BuddyPress uses the "status" field of the "wp_users" table to mark users as spammers. Set it to "1" and it's done!